# create advertise data packet with web Bluetooth API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

how can I create an advertiser with web Bluetooth API? now I am only able to scan nearby Bluetooth devices.

but how can I make my laptop a peripheral device that advertises data to another Bluetooth device to establish a connection? with(web BLE API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [specification of Web Bluetooth](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/) is very clear about it:

*The first version of this specification allows web pages, running on a UA in the Central role, to connect to GATT Servers over either a BR/EDR or LE connection.*

The answer is: you can't.

There is a specification issue for [Advertisement /Beacon Broadcast Support](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/231).

And, a Chromium [Issue 1043409: Bluetooth Advertiser](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1043409) which you can Star to follow.